# How to query a JSON map in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I want to query a `JSON` mysql field as follows:

json:

```
{
    "key1": [
        {
            "firstname": "jane"
        },
        {
            "firstname": "john"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to search for "key1", and extract the `[0].firstname` field, which in this case would be `jane`.

But how can I achieve this with `JSON_EXTRACT()` or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> set @j = '...your json example...';

mysql> select json_unquote(json_extract(@j, '$.key1[0].firstname')) as fn;
+------+
| fn   |
+------+
| jane |
+------+
```